# how to have to sections that resize based on content and another that uses the remaining space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a webapp screen where the header is stuck to the top and the footer stuck to the bottom all the time, and the main content is displayed inbetween with a scroll bar if necessary.

I want to make this possible in multiple devices, so the header and footer can change in height to fit the their content in smaller screens and the main content should use the remaining space.

[image]

Is is possible to create this behaviour with css? (maybe using flexbox?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right - flexbox is perfect for this:

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

header {
    background-color: #0800ff;
}

.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
    background-color: #fec11a;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <header>...</header>
    <div class="content">
        <ol>
            <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
            <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
            <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
            <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
            <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <footer>...</footer>
</section>
```

Notice how I use `height: 100vh` for the `.container` and `flex-grow: 1` for the `.content`. That does the trick.